# hyperref takes me to page 1 in beamer instead of referenced frame

Tags: beamer, hyperref

The following document compiles fine and the link is shown as I would like it to be shown. But when I click on "here" in the resulting pdf I am taken to page 1 instead of the page where the reference is. I would like to be taken to the referenced page.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{the referencing slide}
As you can see \hyperref[refthis]{here}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{random stuff}
in between slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reference this}

I want to reference this frame. \label{refthis}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option would be to use the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism provided by `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{the referencing slide}
As you can see \hyperlink{refthis}{here}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{random stuff}
in between slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reference this}
\hypertarget{refthis}{}
I want to reference this frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another option could be to use `\hyperlink` and the labelling mechanism for frames:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{the referencing slide}
As you can see \hyperlink{refthis}{here}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{random stuff}
in between slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=refthis]
\frametitle{Reference this}
I want to reference this frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for providing more than one option.

Comment: If you want to refer to an environment like lemma, theorem or etc. you can just use its `label` with `hyperlink`.